# ACF (gallery field) compatible Plugin for image carousels on Wordpress post pages

Tags: wordpress, plugins, slider, advanced-custom-fields

I'm looking to find a plugin or another as-simple-as-possible solution to create unique image sliders on individual posts in Wordpress. Ideally the plugin would be free or only require a one-time payment.

The type of system I'm looking for is this:

- each post has its own slider with images unique to that post- no posts will have the same set of images
- images are uploaded into the ACF gallery field on post pages
- sliders are hard-coded into single.php, waiting to loop through gallery images (not using shortcode in the post)
- the slider ui is customizable through a plugin interface in the wp back-end

I'm open to other suggestions for how to do this, although I prefer a solution that requires as little javascript as possible, as I'm on a time crunch and am not the best at writing it! [This looks like a viable option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46996997/integrating-bootstrap-carousel-indicators-with-acf-plugin) if the right plugin isn't available.

Thanks!